# Send the data from WordPress site to mobile redirected site

Tags: json, wordpress, redirect

I have a WordPress site https://techgossip.org  and i have a mobile site which is based on php so i just want to know how i should migrate the data from my WordPress site to that php based site so that my data should be visible on both.

Comment: Why not just use a mobile friendly WP theme?

Comment: No i want another site as my website is already a mobile friendly website but i need another page to look differently and fast accessible through mobile as well

Comment: Can i know whether i can send or use data through JSON?.. if yes?. Than how?. Please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: You can send just about anything through JSON.

Comment: Ok sir. Thanks for helping me out